# Probably scammed by a coin which doesn't allow to sell, only to buy

Tags: solidity, uniswap

As the title says - the coin: https://etherscan.io/token/0x6d85dd21d470e5c1e6af3a5198f0d5ac4dcdd7ef

It only allows you to buy, but not to sell - I might still have a chance to recover my ETH, since I saw this post:

Their are several ways to do that. First be the simplest one, It disabled approve function in the erc20 token contract. That means uniswap cant get your approval for putting the coin to be sold. After this, some of them has a rebase function. When you transfer the tokens to a smart contract address, you will loss 99.99999 percent of it. **I found only an answer to the first problem, by use transfer function, instead transfer from.** To the second problem, I have no answer yet. Just be careful of the tokens that have no source code published. The most dangerous one being the tokens, that had only buying actions. and all the sold actions come from a same address. Those scammers dont even change their address when they deploy new contract. they made 400eth from 80eth. After a few days they just simply empty the liquidity.

I used the Fortmatic wallet with the Zerion App.

---

Thank you for the useless answer - I am asking for help actually, using these commands.

Please read next time :)

Comment: Contact police - this forum is not a scam support.

Comment: Where did you read that? After glancing at the code for a few minutes it is unlikely using approve will unblock token sale.